# Logging in a gem that is used both inside and outside rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rubygems, environment

What's a proper approach to this: I've got a gem that can be used both with or without rails - if it is used within rails, I'd like to re-use rails-services e.g. the configured logger. If it is outside of rails (e.g. in a sinatra-app), I want to fall back on the Logger from stdlib: What is a safe way for a gem to determine, if we're in a rails-app or not?!

I've tried approaches like:

```
@logger = defined?("Rails") ? eval("Rails.logger") : Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

But this only gives me an "uninitialized Constant"...

Answer (score 4):

So close!  Drop the quotes / eval:

```
@logger = defined?(Rails) ? Rails.logger : Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

I'd also encourage that you provide a config hook where the user can specify a `Logger`-compatible log sink.  Defaults are nice but sometimes you need to configure things.